# Mercurial - Ways to resolve abort: error: '' after an hg in/pull

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

A perfectly good repository goes pear shaped after an unknown time.
A simple **hg in** fails with an error
**abort: error: ''**

Sometimes it just hangs for a few minutes without any output.

If I run with **--verbose**, same output.
If I run with **--traceback**, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 88, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 740, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 514, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 830, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 801, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 737, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 471, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 3901, in incoming
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 513, in incoming
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 472, in _incoming
  File "mercurial\bundlerepo.pyo", line 342, in getremotechanges
  File "mercurial\discovery.pyo", line 45, in findcommonincoming
  File "mercurial\setdiscovery.pyo", line 184, in findcommonheads
  File "mercurial\wireproto.pyo", line 116, in plain
  File "mercurial\wireproto.pyo", line 164, in _submitone
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 170, in _call
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 118, in _callstream
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 400, in open
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 418, in _open
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 378, in _call_chain
  File "mercurial\url.pyo", line 314, in http_open
  File "mercurial\keepalive.pyo", line 257, in do_open
URLError: <urlopen error ''>
abort: error: ''
```

No further details...
Does anyone have an idea how to debug this and resolve this? I end up cloning the parent repository again and deleting the old one :-(

**EDIT:** An update - while having these errors, we were working with two LAN networks that had a link between them. Some of the users where in an "old" network and others in the "new" one.
After everyone migrated to the new network, we stopped having these errors.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving this error when there were some problems with bitbucket server (the one I am using as a code repository).
And, eventually, this issue disappeared without my intervention *with some time* (~5-10 min or so...)

If you are using **bitbucket**, you can always check the status/response time of their API using the following link: http://status.bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 1):

Do you using https?

We had the very same problem. We could `hg clone https://repository` without issues. Unless anybody push anything to this (remote) repository, `hg inc` and `hg pull` works fine too. Once the remote repository was changed, `hg inc` either `hg pull` doesn't work anymore and result in the very same traceback (URLError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host). `hg out` either `hg push` works still perfectly.

> Note: We changed the default path in .hg/hgrc to `http://repository`
>   without any troubles regardless of which hg command we used.
>   Of couse we also successfully tested using ssh.

So we went deeper and found something: the maximum allow header size in our loadbalancer which manage the https was too small. After we increased the value, everything works fine, also https :-)

Comment: We are using http only. Also, I just serve the repositories using hgserve running as a service on a CentOS server. The header size is an interesting piece of data. Do you know how to configure it for hgserve?

Comment: Sorry, i don't because we use hgweb.wsgi only. I think you checked your remote repository with hg verify and/or [DebuggingFeatures](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/DebuggingFeatures) already? In our case it clearly was a transport layer problem. In your case, i wonder about your URLError is empty and referring to this i have no idea.

Comment: Do you run hg serve with --errorlog, anything eye-catching there? (hg help serve)